# Collection View, Auto layout UICollectionViewFlowLayout and itemSize

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am really struggling to achieve something fairly simple: 
I would like to create a horizontal collection view where the `UICollectionViewCell`s are the size of the `UICollectionView` itself.

So far so good, I have set up a view controller in the storyboard which looks something like this (notice: collection view is not equal to view controller's size):

```
+--------------------------+
|                          |
|         Some View        |
+--------------------------+ <----- constraint
|                          |
|                          |
|      Collection View     | <----- left and right constraint
|                          |
|                          |
+--------------------------+ <----- constraint
|                          |
|      Some other view     |
+--------------------------+
```

#### Issue:

The collection view's cells do not seem to be the size of the collection view, despite explicitly setting the `itemSize` property of the collection view's flow layout property to the collection view's frame's size in the `viewDidLoad()` method of the controller.

In `viewDidLoad()` I do something like this:

```
let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout.itemSize = self.collectionView.frame.size
layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeZero
layout.footerReferenceSize = CGSizeZero
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
```

#### The strange thing:

When I put this code into `awakeFromNib()`, it seems as if the collectionView is not hooked up -> crash. 
However, when I put the code into `viewDidAppear()`, the collection view shortly appears with wrongly sized cells (whatever is set in the storyboard) and shortly after, **the cells update to the correct size**.

Can anybody help me with this issue ?

### EDIT:

Also seems to work in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. Not sure why, but I guess it is because the constraints have not been applied in `viewDidLoad()` yet.

Answer (score 1):

If collectionView's cells must have static size you should set it in *Interface Builder's Utilities* bar, **here**:

[image]

Otherwise, implement [UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/) protocol's `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:)` method in your delegate controller and return from there desired cell's size.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try the following:
In the ViewController, implement the didLayoutSubviews() function as follows:

```
override func didLayoutSubviews() {
    super.didLayoutSubviews()
    let collectionViewSize = self.collectionView.bounds.size
    if let flowLayout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        flowLayout.itemSize = collectionViewSize
    }
}
```